# Has anyone tried Passware Kit which claims powerful FDE cracking?

Tags: encryption

I always thought full disk encryption on a Linux OS such as Ubuntu was considered uncrackable, even with the most advanced tech tools used by U.S. intelligence agencies. But I just found out there's a software product that easily cracks LUKS full disk encryption. I won't mention the name of the software at the moment because I don't want it to appear I'm promoting it. Their software has apparently been widely available since late 2014.

I'm very surprised to find out FDE is completely vulnerable to anyone with this software. I'm wondering why I've never seen any mention about this in all the Linux info I've read on the web since 2014 about privacy and encryption?  Also wondering if it matters what Ubuntu distro you have (like is FDE any harder to crack on 16 vs. 14)?

Comments are welcome from anyone with knowledge about this apparent total vulnerability of LUKS full disk encryption.

Comment: Some software you won't name cracks full disk encryption? What's next, flying dragons?

Comment: 1. This site isn't a forum. Either you have a clear question related to Ubuntu or not. 2. Is something a common knowledge is an opinion. 3. There is no perfect security. Everything is vulnerable

Comment: Sergiy, you make a good point, so I just edited the title of my post. I hope this is a more reasonable title.

Answer (score 4):

From your comment on Lew's answer, I assume you are referencing [this PDF](https://www.passware.com/files/pr-141204.pdf).

> "Passware pioneers in releasing the commercial software, which recovers
>   LUKS passwords at an incomparable speed of 300 passwords per second"

This is not an exploit, but rather CUDA accelerated brute-forcing. 300/sec is *ridiculously* slow. You need to be at a couple million/sec to crack the password within your lifetime :D

Comment: In fairness, that assumes the pass string was generated with some reasonably sound practice.  There are an awful lot of people out there whose pass consists of 2 words found in the dictionary, their dog's name, or [expletive deleted].   This kind of practice has been common in the past even in military arenas where it was grossly irresponsible, and for all know, may still be.

Comment: @LewRockwellFan Fair point.

Comment: Lew and Android Dev - your comments are very interesting indeed. It's good to know sound passwords are in fact still extremely difficult to brute-force. I wonder if the software making these about LUKS comes with any caveats about the length of the password to be cracked, or knowing at least some piece of the password, or some such?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this issue:

http://hmarco.org/bugs/CVE-2016-4484/CVE-2016-4484_cryptsetup_initrd_shell.html#fix

I'd say, yes, that is common knowledge. I haven't followed it closely, because there are clearly better solutions ANYWAY - however, given how long ago this guy published a fairly simple solution, I'd be surprised if most distro's haven't incorporated it yet. Not astounded, homo saps do the darnedest things, but I would be surprised. Most security holes are fixed shortly after they become public knowledge if not before. This one is mainly notable because it falls in the "Oh shinola, don't we look stupid?" category. But that also means it was probably, I stress PROBABLY, fixed almost instantly.

If you aren't talking about that, and you want to be coy and mysterious, the question isn't answerable. How can anyone say how common unspecified knowledge is?

If you need secure data, use Veracrypt. If you need secure system-generated metadata, use a live disk and swap to a veracrypt crypt or not at all. That's not a total solution, but pretty good.

ADDENDUM IN LIGHT OF COMMENT:
OK, you falsified my if, so now for the "else" part of my answer.
Your question presupposes the truth of the implicit claims for a commercial product. Claims that are made ONLY by people selling it. This is far less concern than the matter I linked to. Brute force password cracking. Yeah, right. So,the elif is: No, that isn't common knowledge because it most likely isn't true. I may be common but I ain't gullible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with posting guidelines here and I thought others might object to mentioning an apparently not well known retail product. Just do a search on "Passware Kit LUKS". I use search engine DuckDuckGo.

Comment: Did you follow your own suggestion and search that string? The only people I see making the claim that you assume is true are the people selling it. So you assume their explicit and implied claims are true and up to date? And pass them on as known fact? Can I interest you in some land in Louisiana?

Comment: Lew, you and Sergiy are correct that my post title was not well thought out to say the least. Just now I edited the title so it doesn't mislead readers, as that was not my intention.